# Comparing two list in a python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have to compare two list. List1 is having a sentences and list2 is having words. SO how to compare the list2 words with list1 sentence each word.

For eg:

```
list1=['hi', 'computer', 'hello', 'world']
list2=['hi my name is computer','welcome to hello world','welcome to python']
```

so here in output I should get first 2 sentences as they have the words containing in list1.

SO how can I achieve it?

Comment: list1 holds only variables, not strings. What did you try? What did you research?

Answer (score -1):

```
list1=['hi', 'computer', 'hello', 'world']
list2=['hi my name is computer','welcome to hello world','welcome to python']
output = []

for i in list2:
    for j in list1:
       if j in i:
          output.append(i)
          break
print(output)
```

Comment: what is x here in append?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo